# limit visual studio workflow to base content type "document"

Tags: visual-studio, workflow, content-type

i want to limit my sharepoint 2010 workflow, which i developed in visual studio 2010, to the base content type "Document". Is there a way to accomplish that? i searched the sdk but have not found anything for that.

br seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to associate a workflow developed in visual studio with a content type. you have to use AssociationCategories Element http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543430.aspx

unfortunately you can not use such a workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item, but thats another problem :)